# SWF doesn't start in Chrome (Pepper Flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

**Update:** I've narrowed it down to Chrome's Pepper Flash. Disabling it (which forces Chrome to use the installed version of Flash that everything else uses), fixes it. But most Chrome users won't have it disabled, so I'm still looking for a solution.

I have a simple game that works fine in Firefox and when debugging in FlashDevelop, but in Chrome, fails to start. It seems to be embedded properly; the white rectangle appears, and gives the Flash options if you right click it. But it doesn't display the graphics or start the game, it just sits there.

The strange thing is, if I do anything else with the page-- for example, if I minimize it and then maximize it again, or switch tabs then switch back-- the game will suddenly appear as it should. I'm not sure what to make of this, other than both of those things would cause the page to be re-rendered (I think).

If I press any key (the game has a keyboard listener), it pops into existence also. So the SWF is definitely there and waiting for commands as it should be, it's just not displaying the initial state.

My first thought was that I'm not loading it properly, but I'm using the standard loading code that FlashDevelop inserts:

```
public function Main():void {
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
   // program entry point
```

I've tried embedding it in many different ways, from a simple `<embed>` or `<object>`, to the more complicated version you sometimes see, which checks for older versions of IE:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
 width="800" height="600" id="movie_name" align="middle"
style="position:fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -300px; margin-left: -400px;">
<param name="movie" value="myswf.swf"/>
<param name="play" value="true" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mapTest6.swf" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="mapTest6.swf"/>
    <param name="play" value="true" />
<!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
    </a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

None seem to have any effect.

Finally, it behaves the same whether it's on my local computer or on a web server. I've also noticed that, once in a while, it *doesn't* happen, which is more puzzling, and makes me wonder if it's a cache issue. But it usually does. *Updated with more information*

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Pepper Flash, the default Chrome flash plugin. Without seeing your code it's difficult to investigate further, but if it's only occurring in-browser I would guess you have a permission issue.

Comment: **Confirmed** it's caused by Pepper Flash, thank you! I disabled it in the Chrome plugins page, which causes it to use the default version of Flash, and it works. Thanks. Now to figure out how to fix it.