# Weird flash player glitch (12.0.0.41) in Chrome only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

Very recently, after the latest Chrome update which includes Adobe Flash Player Version: 12.0.0.41, a flash app that's been running smoothly for years has begun to "hiccup" during one particular function.

**Normal behavior** - User logs in to app. App grabs some xml files then draws a calendar onscreen.

**Hiccup behavior** - User logs in to app. App grabs the xml files but feezes before executing the loadComplete function (according to trace). By freezes, I mean the little load spinner remains onscreen but stops spinning and the calendar doesn't appear onscreen.

**Interesting/maddening notes** - The mouse cursor responds as if the calendar has been drawn (arrow changes to pointer when mouse passes over an invisible calendar day) but according to my trace log the loadComplete and showCal functions haven't fired.

ALSO, any call to a function unfreezes the glitch (e.g. clicking an invisible calendar day, mousingOver a control button, etc. Anything that triggers a function.) and bam! everything's there and the trace log completes as it should.

1. As stated, this glitch only occurs in Chrome with the latest Flash Player update (12,0,0,41).
2. Installing the mozilla version of the flash player debugger (12,0,0,43) and instructing chrome to use it instead fixes the glitch, but using it in chrome opens up a whole new can of worms when it comes to flash player glitches (as is to be expected).
3. Maybe there's nothing I can do and it's just a fault with the latest Chrome flash player build, OR...
4. There's something fundamentally wrong with my code and Chrome's latest flash player is the only plugin that glitches on my "wrong" code?

I'll happily include some code snippets if someone is convinced my code is the problem but am leaving them off for now since this question is enormous. (you're a trooper for sticking with it)

I'm hoping someone else has experienced this or can at least explain it/fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try on Chrome to see what Flash DisplayList contains by making a draw of your calendar into a bitmap and then add this bitmap to stage (or encode your bitmap to jpg/png and send it somewhere) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing very similar symptoms on an application I work on Frankenscarf.  All workarounds have been ineffective thus far.  I can confirm it is specific to 12.0.0.41 Pepper Flash.  I think you might need to wait for google to fix the lasted release...

Comment: Thanks stapler, I too have been trying all sorts of "solutions" to no avail. I found another having the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197879/updated-swf-doesnt-start-in-chrome-pepper-flash?rq=1) Let's hope google straightens it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having problems with Flash 12.0.0.41 on YouTube, videos very laggy and dropping frames all the time even making the video stutter on 320p. I have disabled Chromes built in Flash player though Chrome://plugins, installed Chrome 11.7.700.260 and now have the videos running smoothly even at 1440p. Hopefully they will sort out the bugs soon.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to edit my original post...

UPDATE: I managed to get a workaround going. I set up a periodic timer (triggering every 500ms), that calls invalidateDisplayList() in my largest container. It is horrible, but it works....