# Latest Google Chrome Browser stops Flash (AS3) sending POST data to browser

Tags: google-chrome, flash, http-post

I have the following code in my AS3 Flash code that takes a screenshot within the swf using JPGEncoder and sends it to the url where i write it to a file in PHP.

This code has worked for a long time but since the very latest Google Chrome Update 33.0.1750.146 the function just stops and the page fails to redirect. Nothing gets sent to save.php

I have tested this in Safari, Firefox, IE and lower versions of Chrome up to 33.0.1750.117 and all work perfectly fine.

So surely it's an issue purely with the latest Chrome? Is there anything i can do to solve this?

My code is:

AS3:

```
function createJPG(m:MovieClip, q:Number, fileName:String) {
    var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    jpgSource.draw(stage);
    var jpgScreenshot: BitmapData = new BitmapData(362, 310);
    jpgScreenshot.copyPixels(jpgSource, new Rectangle(288, 89, 362, 310), new Point(0, 0));
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(q);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgScreenshot);
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.url.com/save.php");      
    jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);              
    jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;               
    jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
    var jpgURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();   
    navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_self");
}
```

save.php:

```
$imagefile=''.$imageURL.'';
$fp = fopen($imagefile, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']);
fclose($fp);

header('Location: https://www.url.com/your-image.php');
```

Comment: Welcome to Pepper Flash from your pals at Google. **Quick fix:** Disable Pepper Flash and enable "regular" Flash (probably version 12,0,0,43). **Permanent solution:** I don't know. Pepper Flash seems to be causing a variety of issues (see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197879/updated-swf-doesnt-start-in-chrome-pepper-flash?rq=1) and [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278329/weird-flash-player-glitch-12-0-0-41-in-chrome-only)). No correlations appear to me yet. If you solve your issue, please share. (btw, http URLRequest in aScript but https redirect in the php?)

Comment: Thank you for pushing me into the right direction with Pepper Flash. I managed to find the workaround below after knowing what was causing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching on the pepperflash issue and trying different methods it seems the following simple change works:

replace:

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
```

with:

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain");
```

This now works on Chrome and still on all other browsers

Hope this helps anyone else