# AS3 Writing on server not working on chrome

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

I'm using PNGEncoder to write a file on server, with internet explorer or mozilla the file is writed on server, but when i do it with chrome the file is never writed.

This is the PHP that saves the file to sv:

```
<?php 

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $png = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    header("Content-type: image/png"); 
    echo $png;
}
else echo 'No hay datos binarios';

if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {

    $im =  $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    $fp = fopen($_GET['vFoto'], 'wb');  
    fwrite($fp, $im);
    fclose($fp);

    echo $_GET['vFoto']." se ha guardado en el servidor";
}
else echo 'No hay datos binarios';

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $png = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $img = $_GET["vFoto"];
}
else echo 'No hay datos binarios';

?>
```

This is where i do the request on AS3:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(3750,1300);
    bitmapData.draw(contenedor);

    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData)
    var pngEncoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

    var _ruta:String = "form.php";
    var _nombre_foto:String = new Date().getTime() + "_entrada.png";
    var cabecera:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var urlFoto:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    urlFoto.requestHeaders.push(cabecera);
    urlFoto.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    urlFoto.data = byteArray;
    urlFoto.url = _ruta + "?vFoto=" + _nombre_foto;
    sendToURL(urlFoto);

    trace("Guardado");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into console of chrome? I could suspect that it simply doesn't allow local connections, try to put files on server (could be local server using [mongoose web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29))

or different header like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248217/latest-google-chrome-browser-stops-flash-as3-sending-post-data-to-browser?rq=1)